# Invalid parameter not satisfying: initialSnapshot.numberOfSections == initialSections.count

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

Working on a new project, our team decided to use `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource` to handle our collection views. It works fine, but we're getting (infrequent) crashes logged via an online tool with the message `Invalid parameter not satisfying: initialSnapshot.numberOfSections == initialSections.count`. We can't seem to reproduce this locally.

The crash occurs at the point where we update the data source with new data, specifically at `dataSource.apply(snapshot)`. We're unsure as to how this could happen, as the data is always created the same.

Specifically, the unit working on this one view decided to forgo the creation of a section model and instead decided to use an `Int` as section identifiers, because they didn't want to use sections, just display items. That's one thing I hadn't seen before, but an `Int` satisfies the requirements for identifiers, so the code does compile correctly.

Here is the code:

**Collection View and Data Source creation**

These variables are inside the class of a UIView which is programmatically created.

```
var collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: createCollectionViewLayout())
lazy var dataSource = UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource<Int, URL>(collectionView: collectionView, cellProvider: provideCell(_:indexPath:item:))
```

**Updating the Datasource**

```
func updateUI() {
    var snapshot = dataSource.snapshot()
    snapshot.deleteAllItems()
    snapshot.appendSections([0])
    
    if let urls = viewModel?.imageUrls {
        snapshot.appendItems(urls)
    }

    dataSource.apply(snapshot)
}
```

In all (production) cases I have tested, `viewModel?.imageUrls` is empty on the first call, then contains items on the second call and all calls after that. The number of items usually doesn't change.

I have thought about not using `dataSource.snapshot()` and instead creating a new one, then I also wouldn't have to call `deleteAllItems()` every time. But I don't want to just push this as the solution when I can't be sure whether this really fixes the issue.

Has anyone encountered an issue like this before? Is it correct to use an `Int` as the section identifier? What could be other causes of the crash?

Comment: Your suggestion of creating a new snapshot is probably a good one, the snapshots are _diffable_, and it's the data source's job to do that diffing. If you're manipulating an existing snapshot then you're doing the job of diffing yourself. An Int is fine to use for a section identifier.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you delete only items and each time you add an additional section to your snapshot, which causes an error.
So if your Snapshot already has a "0" section, you do not need to add a new one each time.

In my projects I create a new snapshot every time:

```
var snapshot = NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot<Int, URL>()
snapshot.appendSections([0])
if let urls = viewModel?.imageUrls {
    snapshot.appendItems(urls, toSection: 0)
}
customDataSource.apply(snapshot, animatingDifferences: animate)
```

The same approach is used in WWDC videos.